# Filter by datewise from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am used the following query to get data between two dates

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT cm.description as category, sum((tm.amount - tm.pre_amount)) 
                 FROM transmaster tm 
                 INNER JOIN subcatmasters scm ON tm.scmaster_id = scm.id 
                 INNER JOIN catmasters cm ON scm.catmaster_id = cm.id 
                 WHERE cm.master_id = "+ id + " AND date(tm.txn_date) >= '"
                        + date1
                        + "' AND date(tm.txn_date) <= '"
                        + date2
                        + "'"
                  + " GROUP BY category", null);
```

were id = 1, date1 = 2013-05-05 , date2 = 2013-05-06;

But this query gives me whole table's data , Not between these two dates.

What is wrong with this friends. 
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just an irrelevant suggestion, I always choose to use a Long variable of timestamp when I save data into database, this way querying will always be super efficient.

Comment: What is the format of the values in the `txn_date` column in datebase? And why are you calling the `date` function on them?

Comment: @CL. Format of txn_date is TEXT, To convert the string to date only I called the date function.

Comment: `TEXT` is not a format, it is a type. And the `date` function returns a string anyway.